# Extreme cold protocols

Tags: climate, worldbuilding-resources, temperature

I need to build a world which has incorporated extreme cold (think Iqaluit) into its architecture, daily activity, municipal legislation and culture. This world, although bearing similar temperatures to real places: e.g. Antarctica, is an alternate universe. The environment is a character in the book, the main antagonist and I need to build it for the reader in the novel draft I am working on.

For reference [the average high temperature for the year in Antarctica is about -49 degrees F, while the average low temperature for the continent is about -56 degrees F.](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/average-temperature-antarctica-13726.html)

In an area where the inhabitants must survive extremely cold temperatures, are there:

- Suggestions for proper attire
- Protocols for exiting and entering a (warm) building safely
- General guidelines for outdoor exposure

Comment: Remember the advice from *Arthor Christmas*: "Close the door; it's the north pole!"

Comment: How cold is extremely cold exactly?

Comment: I like the question, but I agree with Vincent.  On world building we deal with some pretty exotic temperatures on a regular basis.. like Minnesota! http://tcotrel.tripod.com/minnesota.html

Comment: If we are talking 'technological advanced civilized society'. The key issue would be to have a completely reliable source of energy. 

For individuals, I'd google 'winter cold survival manual' and add it up a notch while adding refined technological materials and tools. 

While survival in extreme temperatures could be feasible on an organic level through very extreme evolutionary effects I feel that it would conflict with building a 'technological advanced civilized society' - in the same way as an completely-aquatic society would be unlikely.

Comment: Google Oymyakon, the interviews about this place usually have some practical details (http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/05/0512_040512_tvoymyakon.html)

Comment: Thank you for comments: to clarify, I need to build a world which has incorporated extreme cold (think Iqaluit) into its architecture, daily activity, municipal legislation and culture. This world, although bearing similar temperatures to real places: e.g. Antarctica, is an alternate universe. The environment is a character in the book, the main antagonist and I need to build it for the reader in the novel draft I am working on. Thank you.

Comment: Erin, I did some editing on your question to hopefully improve clarity and focus things a bit.  If my edit alters (I don't think I did) your intent or doesn't ask the question you were trying to get to feel free to roll back my change.

Comment: Hi James: Thanks so much. This is a great learning experience. I appreciate the time you have taken to show me a more appropriate format and wording. You have kept the essence of my question(s) intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one: Use revolving doors due to the [stack effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect). Air heated within a building rises (as does all hot air) and escapes through the tops of buildings. This causes lower air pressure in at the bottom of the building, creating a pressure differential. This pressure differential means that it is harder to open doors which open away from the building, [just like a car partially submerged in water](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/open-the-door-of-a-sinking-car/); doors that open into the building will be forced open by the pressure difference, leading to a much colder lobby and a greater energy demand for heating. Revolving doors don't suffer from this problem as they are air tight, making entering a building easy. In fact, [many building in cold cities use them](https://www.wbez.org/shows/curious-city/the-swinging-times-of-chicagos-revolving-doors/20b5db76-1475-4c05-8faf-36a9d1e6ce43).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are resources. Read *Dune* but convert water to heat as the precious resource.

Clothing, buildings, and caches all set up to retain heat or need less.

If you want medical information for humans, just look up first aid and/or survival tips for frostbite and hypothermia.

Keep extremities warm and circulating, stay dry, keep hydrated and warm, and be sure to pay attention to signs like getting tired or comfortable.

At really bad levels, you have to keep eyes from the cold because cornea go transluscent outside a pretty narrow temperature band. After that, (that is, more extremely cold) any exposed skin is in danger of wounding.